# How can I drop a locked table in DB2 on Cloud?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, db2-luw

I'm having trouble with a locked object (table) in my DB2onCloud, I can't drop the table I also did the 'Force Application' but it didn't worked.[image]

[image]

Comment: Provide more details. Is it a table you created? Is the system writing to it?

Comment: Hi @data_henrik, I created a table  which logs the activities of DB2 per schema, but for some reason I can't drop it, when I try to drop the table it says the current transaction has been rolled back because of a deadlock timeout Reason code '68'. I also added another Screen capture to the original post, that maybe can help.

Comment: Not enough detail given in the question. You should edit your question to improve its precision and facts.  __HOW__ do inserts arrive into the table? If from triggers then you have to drop those triggers and wait for those jobs to complete, or kill them. Some jobs when forced-off will simply reconnect automatically. If rows get inserted to the table from other means (stored procedures etc) you have to end *those* jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, how to kill these objects. It seems they are EVENTS  Monitoring. So I just executed this command 'SET EVENT MONITOR capturestats STATE 0', and it works. Thanks for all the help.